# Authorization Exception While implementing "/messages" endpoint in sendgrid API

Tags: java, spring, sendgrid

I am developing a jsf + spring application and in that trying to get all the emails send through the sendgrid api using the ["/messages"](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages) endpoint .

I tried implementing the "/messages" endpoint in Java similar to the "/stats" endpoint mentioned in the example [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/master/examples/stats/stats.java). Below is my code

I am initializing the send grid object in my application context

```
<bean id="sendGrid" class="com.sendgrid.SendGrid">
    <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="my_api_key"/>
</bean>
```

Then I am using the autowired instance of that object in my service bean as follows:

```
com.sendgrid.Request request = new Request();
try {
   request.setMethod(Method.GET);
   request.setEndpoint("messages");
   request.addQueryParam("limit", "10");
   request.addQueryParam("query", "status='processed'");
   com.sendgrid.Response response=sendGrid.api(request);
   LOGGER.debug(response.getBody());
} catch (IOException e) {
   LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}
```

However I am receiving the following exception

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Request returned status Code 400 Body:{"errors":[{"message":"authorization required"}]}
at com.sendgrid.Client.executeApiCall(Client.java:287)
at com.sendgrid.Client.get(Client.java:163)
at com.sendgrid.Client.api(Client.java:308)
at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.makeCall(SendGrid.java:203)
at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.api(SendGrid.java:225)
```

Since I am able to send e-mail and receive stats successfully. I don't think authorization should be the problem here. Am I going wrong somewhere or am I missing something?

Any guesses or leads welcome. Thanks

Comment: Does your API key have required permissions to do that? You can check it on the API Keys settings page.

Comment: I contacted the sendgrid support team and It was an API Key issue. Since I was trying out the free account, I did not have access to that particular endpoint. However once I upgraded to a paid account with the email activity add on, It worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the sendgrid support team and It was an API Key issue. Since I was trying out the free account, I did not have access to that particular endpoint. However once I upgraded to a paid account with the email activity add on, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like Pranay said, You have to purchase Add-On named as "Extended Email Activity History" located at (once you logged in with send grid, look for)  
 Settings → Account_Details → Product_Page → Scroll down to add-ons → then select "Extended Email Activity History" and add to your plan. (Current cost of this add-on is $12/month* & I don not understand meaning of * here)

You can check following link for sendgrid code snippet 
https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages

 
Hope this helps
PK

Comment: `*` is for `*Taxes may apply`